# Spring Data Rest does not update foreign keys

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

So, I have two entities:

```
Orders
    id
    product_id
    quantity
    ...

Products
    id
    name
    desc
    ...
```

So that my Orders table looks like this (not really but you get the idea):

```
Orders
==================================
    id        product_id        quantity
    1         42                100
    2         55                150
    3         99                200
```

Now when I perform a `PUT` on the `Orders` resource, I can change the quantity all day long.  But any attempt to change the `product_id` results in nothing.  My mapping should be correct because I can query orders and then reference the product.

But just as a reference, my mapping is like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Orders")
public class Order {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)  // also tried LAZY
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Products")
public class Product {
    ...
    @Column(name="ProductKey")
    private product_id;
    ...
}
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Oh, using SQL Server 2008, spring-data-rest-webmvc 1.0.0-RELEASE, spring-data-jpa

Thanks.

Comment: Why did you display twice the same code ?

Comment: I don't see any `Cascade` set on the `Product`s in `Orders`.  Since `product_id` is part of `Product`, I think you need to either save those or setup a cascade.